# Call an API inside another API - Node.js with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongoose

I have an API with certain routes for a company, example:

```
// Company
routes.get("/company", companyController.getCompanies); // Obter todas as empresas
routes.post("/company", companyController.saveCompany); // Registar uma empresa
```

And a company class has this:

```
const Company = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name : { type: String, required: true },
    description : { type: String, required: true },
    location : { type: String, required: true },
    numberOfEmployees: { type: Number, required: false },
    subjectAreas: { type: String, required: true },
    username : { type: String, required: true },
    email : { type: String, required: true },
    password : { type: String, required: true }
  }
)
```

But now I want to know the weather in the company location.
Do I need to create another route with my API? Where can I start?
I'm thinking about using Accuweather API but have no idea how to start. Any help?

I'm using node.js, javascript

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can call Accuweather API inside your current controller and save the response in DB

Comment: How can I call inside my controller?